# Learn SQLite Manager( mozilla add ons) on XCODE 

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, xcode4

I have learned from the net that SQLite Manager which is an addon for mozilla firefox. I know how to create the database in SQlite manager. But i dont know how i can connect it to the code and edit, delete, move, erase, rewrite, etc. the data at runtime.

In short how to manage the data in run time and where should I do this? Are there any functions in Objective-C for database management ? Or is there any other better way for database management on XCode?

Comment: Please search this site ("[objective-c] [sqlite]") and your favorite search engine. There's tons of stuff out there on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below link might help you

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/